# TypeScript Assertion for multiple class properties not being undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have a class that represents a Bluetooth device that has properties that are undefined until the Bluetooth device is connected:

```js
import Sblendid, { Peripheral, Service } from "@sblendid/sblendid";
import converters, { Services, Converters } from "./converters";
import Events from "./events";

default class DE1 {
    private machine?: Peripheral;
    private service?: Service<Converters>;
    private events?: Events;

    async connect(): Promise<void> {
        if (this.isConnected()) return;
        this.machine = await Sblendid.connect<Services>("DE1");
        this.service = await this.machine.getService("a000", converters);
        this.events = new Events(this.service);
        this.events.emit("connected");
    }

    async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
        if (!this.isConnected()) return;
        await this.machine.disconnect();
        this.events.emit("disconnected");
        this.events = undefined;
        this.machine = undefined;
        this.service = undefined;
    }

    public isConnected(): boolean {
        if (!this.machine) return false;
        return this.machine.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Now this code will fail because the `disconnect` method assumes `this.machine` and `this.events` can be `undefined`. Only I know that the first line

```js
if (!this.isConnected()) return;
```

will make sure they are actually not `undefined`.

I am wondering how to tell `TypeScript`.

I read about [Assertion Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

I wonder if I can tell `TypeScript` that if `this.isConnected()` returns `true` the three properties `this.machine`, `this.service` and `this.events` are *not `undefined`*, and if so, how.

Comment: `isConnected(): this is this & {machine: Peripheral, events: Events, service: Service<Converters>}` same method body

Comment: A lazier option is to use the `!` member syntax.  `private machines!: Service<Converters>;`. This tells the compiler that it doesn't need to set the property values in the constructor, but we can assume they exist by the time we use them.